# how to combine contents of 2 txt files in unix..i know the cat command can do this but how?

Tags: unix, combine

I need to combine contents of 2 text files, word by word.

The script takes every word from file 1 and combines with file 2.
it adds all the combined words in file 3.

Example:

```
File1        File2         
WordA1       WordB1
WordA2       WordB2
WordA3       WordB3
```

Output: `WordA1 WordB1 WordA2 WordB2 WordA3 WordB3`

How do we do this using the cat command?

Comment: Can you actually write a question and then post it? An edit every 5 seconds is annoying. Esp. if you get multiple answers before you finished editing (and while the actual question seems to be mutating to a different question).

Comment: I don't think cat would do that. You're probably going to need at the very least something like cut, and a pretty interesting bash script. Using a proper programming language like python is very likely a better idea.

Comment: @sam: I edited the file and added an example. Please check if that is actually what you wanted. Also, do you really need to use cat? It is possible but probably not the best way to solve this. If you do not require the use of the cat command but just the described result, then please use the edit function to remove the `How do we do this using the cat command?` line.

Comment: @Hennes, i just read his revisions, he need `A1B1 A1B2 A2B3 A2B1 A2B2`..., a small script with 2 loops is what he wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this :

```
paste file1 file2
```

If you want it on only one like :

```
paste file1 file2 | sed -n '2,$p' | paste -sd ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file1 file2 > outputfile.txt
```

Comment: but i need to combine the words.not just combine the files.

Comment: that cannot be done from the cat command, at least not alone.

Comment: Aye. not alone. You can cat all the files num_words_in_file times and use cut -d' ' -f $increasing field. Seeems horribly wasteful and only useful if you *need* to use cat (e.g. for a homework question).

Answer (score 0):

```
[max@localhost ~]$ cat file1
wordA1
wordA2
wordA3
```

```
[max@localhost ~]$ cat file2
wordB1
wordB2
wordB3
```

```
[max@localhost ~]$ paste -s file1 file2 > file3
[max@localhost ~]$ cat file3 
wordA1  wordA2  wordA3
wordB1  wordB2  wordB3
```

Comment: sorry for the multi edits.im new here.

Comment: i need A1B1 A1B2 A2B3 A2B1 A2B2.but all in a single line